# Nested Model validation errors show on create but not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a `Developer` model that `:has_one` `User` model. This allows for authentication and stuff across different user types.

When I create a new Developer with incorrect User data, it renders the list of validation errors. When I update a Developer with incorrect User data, it just re-renders the edit form (as it should) but doesn't show the validation errors.

My validation error display code sits in my fields partial for the form so that shouldn't make a difference.

I feel like the issue is in the way I'm trying to update my models.

```
def update
  @developer = Developer.find(params[:id])
  if @developer.user.update_attributes(params[:user]) && @developer.update_attributes(params[:developer])
    flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
    sign_in @developer.user
    redirect_to @developer
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

and my `User` validations aren't anything fancy:

```
validates :name,  presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

I've read at least 10 different similar-sounding posts but I haven't found anything that's helped. Any help would be great.

**Edit**

When I submit my `update` form, the following params come through

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"70xmNVxxES7lK2bSIIul/i5GaiJhB9+B5bV/bUVFlTs=", "user"=>{"name"=>"foo", "email"=>"foo@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "developer"=>{"skype_name"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"11"}
```

It still doesn't do the `User` validations. If I do the following via the console, it works though (i.e. it saves when the params are good and fails when the params are bad):

```
Developer.last.update_attributes(:user_attributes => {:name => "test updated", :email => "test@example.com", :password => "123456", :password_confirmation => "123456"})
```

So the only thing that seems different to me is the `:user_attributes` rather than just `:user` that my form is giving me. How do I change that?

**Edit 2**

Relevant part of my `_fields` partial for the form:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= fields_for :user do |user| %>
  <%= user.label :name %>
  <%= user.text_field :name %>

  <%= user.label :email %>
  <%= user.text_field :email %>

  <%= user.label :password %>
  <%= user.password_field :password %>

  <%= user.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
  <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation %>
<% end %>
```

and my `Developer#edit` action:

```
def edit
  @developer = Developer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save user and developer separately, you can manage to save the user through developer model like this,

```
    <%= form_for(@developer) do |f| %>

      ... developer's attribute ...

           <%= f.fields_for :user do |ff| %>
            ... user's attribute ...
```

in controller, only

```
   @developer = Developer.find(params[:id])
   if @developer.update_attributes(params[:developer])
       ....
```

In developer model, you just need to add,

```
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
```

and

```
     attr_accessible :user_attribute
```

now form_for will automatically display the validation errors of user's model as well.

see this link for more details http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Ok cool. I had tried just doing `@developer.update_attributes(params[:developer])` but it said something about mass assignment to protected attributes or something like that. I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` but was missing the `attr_accessible :user_attribute`. I'll try it later and mark as correct if it works :)

Comment: I tried adding in `attr_accessible :user_attribute` but that didn't help. If I'm calling `@developer.update_attributes(params[:developer])`, surely that just updated the Developer attributes and not the User attributes? How do I get it to do both?

Comment: make sure that params[:developer][:user_attributes] is not nil.

Comment: Is your "controller" code right? It looks like you just copy pasted. Is that what you meant to do? What I'm wanting is to either update the Developer and the User or update neither, hence, wanting to do it in 1 step if possible.

Comment: Mike you are right, two lines were pasted twice by mistake. It quite possible to update the two model in one step. I would like to suggest you to try this all stuff in console first and then go for actual form. You will better know from console if any thing is going wrong.

Comment: I've tried via the console and edited the question. Would you mind having another look? :)

Comment: can you please list down you form here? looking like something is wrong with it.

Comment: As I edited my answer, I realised I'd used `fields_for` rather than `f.fields_for`. Then I checked your answer and that was the problem. It all seems to work now. Thanks a lot for the help!